OSError: [Errno -9996] Invalid input device (no default output device)
So I have already installed pyaudio but it returns an error, I'm using WSL.
import assemblyai as aai
import openai
import elevenlabs
from queue import Queue
from elevenlabs.client import ElevenLabs
from elevenlabs import play
# Set API keys
aai.settings.api_key = "d7d4648d801c4f3380fa16a842d73025"
openai.api_key = "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"
 

client = ElevenLabs(
  api_key="d7756af4467de134051e46b2c24425ab" # replace with your actual API key
)
transcript_queue = Queue()

def on_data(transcript: aai.RealtimeTranscript):
    if not transcript.text:
        return
    if isinstance(transcript, aai.RealtimeFinalTranscript):
        transcript_queue.put(transcript.text + '')
        print("User:", transcript.text, end="\r\n")
    else:
        print(transcript.text, end="\r")

def on_error(error: aai.RealtimeError):
    print("An error occured:", error)

# Conversation loop
def handle_conversation():
    while True:
        transcriber = aai.RealtimeTranscriber(
            on_data=on_data,
            on_error=on_error,
            sample_rate=44_100,
        )

        # Start the connection
        transcriber.connect()

        # Open  the microphone stream
        microphone_stream = aai.extras.MicrophoneStream()

        # Stream audio from the microphone
        transcriber.stream(microphone_stream)

        # Close current transcription session with Crtl + C
        transcriber.close()

        # Retrieve data from queue
        transcript_result = transcript_queue.get()

        # Send the transcript to OpenAI for response generation
        response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
            model = 'gpt-4',
            messages = [
                {"role": "system", "content": 'You are a highly skilled AI, answer the questions given within a maximum of 1000 characters.'},
                {"role": "user", "content": transcript_result}
            ]
        )

        #text = response['choices'][0]['message']['content']
        text = "AssemblyAI is the best YouTube channel for the latest AI tutorials."

        # Convert the response to audio and play it
        audio = client.generate(
            text=text,
            voice="Bella" # or any voice of your choice
        )

        print("\nAI:", text, end="\r\n")

        play(audio)

handle_conversation()

ALSA lib confmisc.c:1334:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5701:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
